# Ho can I make the specific exception's ExceptionHandler code to work instead of the code to handle "Exception" with @ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring-boot, exception, controller-advice

I'm using @ControllerAdvice in Spring Boot project to handle Stripe's Card Exception but every time when this exception is thrown the code to handle Exception works instead of the code to handle specific Card Exception.

this is what I am doing :

"This is the Api that throws he exception - CardException on entering wrong Card details"

```
@PostMapping("/charge")
    public String chargePayment(HttpServletRequest request) throws CardException, AuthenticationException, InvalidRequestException, StripeException { 
.......
}
```

"This is my Exeption handling class code"

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class StripeExceptionHandler {

// I want this to work when the above method/Api throws CardException.
    @ExceptionHandler(CardException.class)
    public String handleCardException(CardException cardException, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("exception","CardException : "+ cardException.toString());
        model.addAttribute("redirectUrl", "contribute");
        return "exceptionpage";
    }

// But every time CardException is thrown this code works instead of the above specific code.
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String handleGlobalExceptions(Exception exception, WebRequest webRequest, Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("exception", exception.getMessage());
        model.addAttribute("redirectUrl", webRequest.getDescription(false));
        return "exceptionpage";
    }
}
```

Comment: According to Spring's documentation, `By default, the methods in an @ControllerAdvice apply globally to all controllers`. However, it seems like you might have other configs that are affecting this. Can you try to add basePackages and see if it would solve the problem? `@ControllerAdvice(basePackages = {"com.whatever.your.controller.package"})`

Comment: Didn't worked. only the code to handle a Parent Exception class is working. code to handle child Exception class doesn't work if I implement the code to handle its Parent.
even after specifying the base package in @ControllerAdvice.

Answer (score 0):

(if this question is still unresolved)

In my case, the problem was, that the `Exception` for what I created the `ExceptionHandler` was just the cause of another `Exception`, so that's why the `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` caught it instead.

So maybe you could check if the `Exception` is actually of that class in the debugger.